# How to manage multiple modelformset_factory in one page?

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

I am working on a task that have 5 forms.
Two of these are forms and others are being generated using modelformset_factory.

Background:

I need to build a view that handles these 5 forms:

```
CdnUrl
|-- Http
    |-- Location
        | -- HttpRedirect
        | -- HttpProxy
    |-- Location
        | -- HttpRedirect
        | -- HttpProxy
    |-- Location
        | -- HttpRedirect
        | -- HttpProxy
```

HttpProxy and HttpRedirect can not be inserted simultaneously. Just HttpRedirect or HttpProxy, not both.

## forms.py

```
class OneRequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OneRequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for form in self.forms:
            form.empty_permitted = False


class CustomLocationFormset(OneRequiredFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomLocationFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.forms[0].fields["uri"].initial = "/"
        self.forms[0].fields["uri"].widget.attrs["readonly"] = True

    def clean(self):
        super(CustomLocationFormset, self).clean()
        if self.forms[0].cleaned_data["uri"] != "/":
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"Your first URI must be '/'")


class CustomInlineStreamingFormset(BaseFormSet):
    pass


class CdnUrlForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CdnUrl
        fields = ("account", )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.accounts_range = kwargs.pop("accounts_range", None)

        super(CdnUrlForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.accounts_range:
            self.fields["account"].queryset = self.accounts_range

    def save(self, commit=True, **kwargs):
        service = kwargs.pop("service", None)
        instance = super(CdnUrlForm, self).save(commit=False)
        if service:
            instance.service = service
        if commit:
            instance.save()
        return instance


class HttpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    CONFIGURATION_STATE_CHOICES = [
        (True, "Enabled"),
        (False, "Disabled")
    ]

    GZIP_CHOICES = [
        (True, "On"),
        (False, "Off"),
    ]

    configuration_state = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=CONFIGURATION_STATE_CHOICES,
                                                 widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                                 initial=True)
    gzip = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=GZIP_CHOICES,
                                  widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                  initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Http
        fields = ("cdnurl_allow_content_access",
                  "configuration_state",
                  "protocol_policy",
                  "ssl_certificate",
                  "gzip",
                  "cname_url",
                  "origin",
                  "host_header",
                  # admin fields
                  "manual_configuration",
                  "minimum_object_lifetime",
                  "connect_timeout",
                  "read_timeout",
                  "granularity_file_size", )


class LocationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ("uri", )


class HttpRedirectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = HttpRedirect
        fields = ("domain_redirect", )


class HttpProxyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    CACHE_QUERY_STRING_CHOICES = [
        (True, "Yes"),
        (False, "No (Improves Caching)"),
    ]

    cache_query_string = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=CACHE_QUERY_STRING_CHOICES,
                                                widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                                                initial=False)

    class Meta:
        model = HttpProxy
        fields = ("end_user_caching",
                  "expires_range",
                  "expires_value",
                  "cdn_object_caching",
                  "cdn_object_lifetime",
                  "allowed_http_methods",
                  "forward_cookie",
                  "white_list_cookie",
                  "cache_query_string",
                  "proxy_headers",
                  "remove_headers",
                  "comments", )

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(HttpProxyForm, self).clean()
        expires_range = cleaned_data.get("expires_range")
        expires_value = cleaned_data.get("expires_value")

        if expires_range and expires_range.upper() == "Y" and expires_value > 10:
            raise forms.ValidationError(u"Invalid Range (Max is 10 Years)")

        return cleaned_data
```

So my initial idea is that I must have 2 forms and 3 modelformsets.

CdnUrlForm and HttpForm are my forms.
LocationForm, HttpRedirectForm and HttpProxyForm will be used to build my formsets.

I am doing this because to save a consistent record I need:
- CdnUrl data
- Http data
- Location data
- HttpProxy OR HttpRedirect data

My design is:

CdnUrlForm (only one form)
HttpForm (only one form)
Location (I can insert several location per page)
HttpProxy (I can insert only one HttpProxy per Location)
HttpRedirect (I can insert only one HttpRedirect per location)

Here is my view:

## views.py

```
@reversion.create_revision()
@login_required
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_active)
def create_configuration(request, service_type, service_code):
    contact_logged = request.user.get_profile()
    accounts_range = contact_logged.account.get_self_and_children()

    contact_services = get_contact_services(request)

    service = Services.objects.get(url_name=service_code)

    cdn_url_form = CdnUrlForm(request.POST or None, accounts_range=accounts_range)

    http_form = HttpForm(request.POST or None)

    LocationFormSet = modelformset_factory(Location, form=LocationForm, formset=CustomLocationFormset, extra=2,
                                           can_delete=False)
    location_form_set = LocationFormSet(request.POST or None)

    RedirectFormSet = modelformset_factory(HttpRedirect, form=HttpRedirectForm, can_delete=False, extra=2)

    ProxyFormSet = modelformset_factory(HttpProxy, form=HttpProxyForm, can_delete=False, extra=2)

    redirect_form_set = RedirectFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=HttpRedirect.objects.none())
    proxy_form_set = ProxyFormSet(request.POST or None, queryset=HttpProxy.objects.none())

    if request.method == "POST":
        if cdn_url_form.is_valid():
            cdn_url_instance = cdn_url_form.save(commit=False, service=service)

            if http_form.is_valid() and location_form_set.is_valid():
                http_instance = http_form.save(commit=False)

                for location_form in location_form_set:
                    location_instance = location_form.save(commit=False)

                    if redirect_form_set.is_valid():
                        for redirect_form in redirect_form_set:
                            cdn_url_instance.save()
                            redirect_instance = redirect_form.save(commit=False)
                            http_instance.cdn_url = cdn_url_instance
                            http_instance.save()
                            location_instance.http = http_instance
                            location_instance.save()
                            redirect_instance.location = location_instance
                            redirect_instance.save()

                    if proxy_form_set.is_valid():
                        for proxy_form in redirect_form_set:
                            cdn_url_instance.save()
                            proxy_instance = proxy_form.save(commit=False)
                            http_instance.cdn_url = cdn_url_instance
                            http_instance.save()
                            location_instance.http = http_instance
                            location_instance.save()
                            proxy_instance.location = location_instance
                            proxy_instance.save()

                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("dashboard"))

    return render_to_response(
        "cdnsetup/configuration/create_or_edit.html",
        {"contact_services": contact_services,
         "service_type": service_type,
         "cdn_url_form": cdn_url_form,
         "http_form": http_form,
         "location_form_set": location_form_set,
         "redirect_form_set": redirect_form_set,
         "proxy_form_set": proxy_form_set},
        RequestContext(request),
    )
```

Whenever I post data to this view, it looks like my modelformsets are not being validated. Of course my code is wrong, but I don't know how to handle all these forms to do the following:

Insert data from CdnUrlForm
Insert data from HttpForm
Insert all Locations

For every Location, check if HttpRedirectForm instances are valid. If they are valid, I can ONLY insert HttpRedirectForm data, not HttpProxy (so I would ignore any data in HttpProxyForm).

Here is my models:

## models.py

```
import uuid
from datetime import date
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from azionmanager.validators.urls_validator import validate_domain


class CdnUrl(models.Model):
    cdn_url = models.CharField(_("cdn url"), max_length=255, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey("controlpanel.Accounts", null=False, blank=False)
    # related service
    service = models.ForeignKey("controlpanel.Services", null=False, blank=False)
    # sequential field used to create cdn url field
    sequential = models.IntegerField()

    @classmethod
    def get_next_sequence(cls, account, service):
        """Get the next sequential number if CDN URL does not exist yet."""
        sequential = cls.objects.filter(account=account, service=service).defer("sequential").order_by("-sequential")
        if not sequential:
            return 1
        return sequential[0].sequential + 1

    def create_cdn_url(self):
        self.cdn_url = "{sequential}{account}.{service}.{domain}". \
            format(sequential=self.sequential, account=self.account.client_id, service=self.service.url_name,
                   domain=settings.CDN_DOMAIN)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("cdnsetup.views.services_setup.edit_configuration",
                       args=[self.service.service_type.lower(),
                             self.service.url_name,
                             self.id])

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.sequential = CdnUrl.get_next_sequence(self.account, self.service)
        self.create_cdn_url()
        super(CdnUrl, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Http(models.Model):
    STATUS_CODES_CHOICES = [
        ("P", "Pending"),
        ("V", "Valid"),
        ("I", "Invalid"),
        ("L", "Locked")
    ]

    PROTOCOL_CHOICES = [
        ("HTTP", "HTTP"),
        ("HTTPS", "HTTPS"),
        ("HTTP+HTTPS", "HTTP & HTTPS"),
    ]

    GRANULARITY_FILE_SIZE_CHOICES = [
        ("SF", "Small Files"),
        ("LF", "Large Files"),
    ]

    cdn_url = models.ForeignKey(CdnUrl)

    # distribution settings

    cdnurl_allow_content_access = models.BooleanField(_("allow content access through CDN url"), default=True)
    configuration_state = models.BooleanField(_("configuration state"), default=True)
    protocol_policy = models.CharField(_("viewer protocol policy"), max_length=10, choices=PROTOCOL_CHOICES, null=False,
                                       blank=False,
                                       default=PROTOCOL_CHOICES[0][0])
    ssl_certificate = models.CharField(_("ssl certificate"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    gzip = models.BooleanField(_("gzip content"), default=False)

    cname_url = models.TextField(_("cname url"), max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    # origin settings

    origin = models.CharField(_("origin domain name"), validators=[validate_domain], max_length=255, null=False,
                              blank=False)
    host_header = models.CharField(validators=[validate_domain], max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    # used after configuration is saved
    status = models.CharField(_("validation status"), max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CODES_CHOICES, editable=False,
                              default=STATUS_CODES_CHOICES[0][0])

    # admin settings

    manual_configuration = models.BooleanField(_("manual configuration"), default=False)
    minimum_object_lifetime = models.IntegerField(_("minimum object lifetime"), default=60, null=False, blank=True)
    connect_timeout = models.IntegerField(_("connect timeout"), default=60, null=True, blank=True)
    read_timeout = models.IntegerField(_("read timeout"), default=120, null=True, blank=True)
    granularity_file_size = models.CharField(_("granularity file size"), max_length=2,
                                             choices=GRANULARITY_FILE_SIZE_CHOICES,
                                             default=GRANULARITY_FILE_SIZE_CHOICES[1][0],
                                             null=False, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "<{cdn_url}>: {cname_url}".format(cdn_url=self.cdn_url, cname_url=self.cname_url)


class Location(models.Model):
    http = models.ForeignKey(Http)
    uri = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)

    created_at = models.DateField(_("create date"), default=date.today)
    updated_at = models.DateField(_("update date"), auto_now_add=True)


class HttpRedirect(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="redirect")

    domain_redirect = models.URLField(_("domain redirect"), max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)


class HttpProxy(models.Model):
    RANGE_UNITS = [
        ("S", "Seconds"),
        ("M", "Minutes"),
        ("H", "Hours"),
        ("D", "Days"),
        ("W", "Weeks"),
        ("M", "Months"),
        ("Y", "Years"),
    ]

    GRANULARITY_FILE_SIZE = [
        ("SF", "Small Files"),
        ("LF", "Large Files"),
    ]

    CACHING_CHOICES = [
        ("O", "Use Origin Cache Headers"),
        ("C", "Customize"),
    ]

    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name="proxy")

    # cache settings

    end_user_caching = models.CharField(_("end user caching"), max_length=1, choices=CACHING_CHOICES,
                                        default=CACHING_CHOICES[0][0])
    expires_range = models.CharField(_("expires_range"), max_length=2, choices=RANGE_UNITS, default=RANGE_UNITS[3][0])
    expires_value = models.IntegerField(_("expires_value"), default=30)

    cdn_object_caching = models.CharField(_("cdn object caching"), max_length=1, choices=CACHING_CHOICES,
                                          default=CACHING_CHOICES[0][0])
    cdn_object_lifetime = models.IntegerField(_("cdn object lifetime"), default=10080, null=False, blank=False)

    allowed_http_methods = models.TextField(_("allowed http methods"), max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    forward_cookie = models.CharField(_("forward cookie"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    white_list_cookie = models.CharField(_("white list cookie"), max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    cache_query_string = models.BooleanField(_("cache query string"), default=False)

    proxy_headers = models.TextField(_("proxy headers"), null=True, blank=True)
    remove_headers = models.TextField(_("remove headers"), null=True, blank=True)

    # add comments to the configuration
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.cdn_object_lifetime < self.location.http.cdn_url.minimum_object_lifetime:
            raise ValidationError(u"Object lifetime can not be less than {minimum_object_lifetime}".format(
                minimum_object_lifetime=self.location.http.cdn_url.minimum_object_lifetime))

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "<{cdn_url}>: {uri}".format(cdn_url=self.cdn_url, uri=self.uri)
```

Finally, I don't want Location instances to be inserted if they have no HttpProxy or HttpRedirect instances attached to them. And like I said earlier, I can have multiple locations per page and HttpProxy OR HttpRedirect for which one of these Locations.
What do I need to do to handle these forms in the same page?

Comment: I take it they are all inside one form tag in the html? Try giving each form a prefix, helps avoid collisions between field names https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#prefixes-for-forms

Comment: When I have a lot of formsets in one view, I put them in a dictionary so that I can iterate over the lot of them. You however have specific requirements for validation, (as opposed to checking each form's "is_valid") so that might not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Couple things I might try to see if everything is working. First, open the shell and create some forms and bind them to data and validate them manually. Often this will help get you one step further in your investigation.

Next, whenever working with multiple forms and formsets, do as @ Anentropic mentions and use prefixes. I just recently overcame a problem that was beautifully solved with using `prefix` and `auto_id` arguments.

It looks like you have a complex form design, so it's likely you are running into a few problems and it's hard to figure out which because you have some many moving parts.